# How to get Hub Context with Azure SignalR?

Tags: azure, signalr

I'm using Azure SignalR service. I want to use SignalR hub context in console app. In the old version, I could call:

```
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext
```

with previously registered:

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis(redisHost, redisPort, string.Empty, redisEventName);
```

How can I do this with Azure SignalR in application without ASP.net core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure SignalR Service doesn't support ASP.NET SignalR in current phase (public preview). Because Azure SignalR Service is based on ASP.NET Core SignalR. There are a lot of gaps to fill in order to support ASP.NET SignalR. We are actively working on it. You can follow up the progress on this issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/issues/101 .

-- edit on Nov. 8

Azure SignalR Service is now public preview the support of ASP.NET SignalR. Hope you didn't miss it.
https://github.com/azure/azure-signalr#aspnet-signalr